# dragging ckeditor toolbar in inline editing

Tags: ckeditor

As CKEditor documentation is really poor, I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere.

Is it possible to configure CKeditor so that toolbar would be draggable in inline editing mode?
I'd like to be able to move it around.

If so, how is it possible to set that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such option available by default. However, you can achieve that by placing toolbar in your own container and adding a drag&drop handler to it, for example using some jQuery UI feature.

To be able to move toolbar to your own container you need to use the [sharedspace](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace) plugin (build CKEditor package with it) and set the [`config.sharedSpaces`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-sharedSpaces) option as is described in the so poor documentation.